# am i using actionlistener properly

Tags: java, multithreading, actionlistener

Im trying to understand why this program does not work. Am i using the actionlistener properly why does it not show the time elapsed from when the thread is running but the thread is not running and i see nothing on the screen.
what am i doing wrong or this is the wrong way of using the ActionListener class
or am i not using it properly, here is the code for all the files.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

public class Timer extends Thread {
    private int iTime = 0;
    private ActionListener itsListener = null;

    public Timer() {
        super(); // allocates a new thread object
        iTime = 0; // on creation of this object set the time to zero
        itsListener = null; // on creation of this object set the actionlistener
                            // object to null reference
    }

    public synchronized void resetTime() {
        iTime = 0;
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener event) throws TooManyListenersException {
        if (event == null)
            itsListener = event;
        else
            throw new TooManyListenersException();
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener event) {
        if (itsListener == event)
            itsListener = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                this.sleep(100);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                // do nothing
            }
            iTime++;

            if (itsListener != null) {
                String timeString = new String(new Integer(iTime).toString());

                ActionEvent theEvent = new ActionEvent(this,
                        ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, timeString);

                itsListener.actionPerformed(theEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

next file

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

public class TextTimeDemonStration extends Object implements ActionListener {
    private Timer aTimer = null; // null reference for this object

    public TextTimeDemonStration() {
        super();

        aTimer = new Timer();

        try {
            aTimer.addActionListener(this);
        } 
        catch (TooManyListenersException exception) {
            // do nothing
        }

        aTimer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String theCommand = e.getActionCommand();

        int timeElapsed = Integer.parseInt(theCommand, 10);

        if (timeElapsed < 10) {
            System.out.println(timeElapsed);
        }
        else
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

the last file the main class running the program from

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextTimeDemonStration test = new TextTimeDemonStration();    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TextTimeDemonStration` class, you called `aTimer.addActionListener(this);` to assign an action listener

But in your `Timer.addActionListener()` method, in the `if else` block, you wrote

```
if (event == null)
    itsListener = event;
else
    throw new TooManyListenersException();
```

Since `this` is not null, it will throw `TooManyListenersException` exception which will be caught.

After which you start the timer. But, since `itsListener` is null after the initialisation, in your `Timer.run()` method, the `if` block will never be executed. Therefore, nothing is done.

Fix up the logic at `Timer.addActionListener()` method and it should work just fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: im not sure what you mean how do i go about fixing it im new to java right now and i do not understand what you mean could you show me some code